# How to draw a multirow table with invisible column lines using Latex

Tags: tables

I am trying to draw a table that; the first row has 2 columns (invisible column lines), the second row has 4 columns, and the rest of the 2 rows have 6 rows as shown in the attached image. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The second table of https://texdoc.org/serve/booktabs/0 is very similar to what you are looking for...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Can you put a better photo with horizontal such as to see if [mathpix](https://mathpix.com/) can find the good code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rmano pointed out, the table looks very similar to the one in the `booktabs` manual so using `booktabs` you can create this

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}} \toprule
        & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$W_1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$W_2$}\\ \cmidrule(l){3 - 6}
        DATA & LY & A & B & A & B\\ \midrule
        1 & 7 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
        2 & 7 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]